# Avoid passing accumulation parameter in tail recursive call

Tags: scala

Say I want to do a simple conversion of strings to ints thus:

> List("1", "3", "55", "x", "7") => List(1, 3, 55, 7)

One way to do this would be the following recursive call:

```
def recurse1(strs: List[String]): List[Int] = strs match {
    case h :: t =>
        try {
            h.toInt :: recurse1(t)
        }
        catch {
            case _ : java.lang.NumberFormatException =>
                recurse1(t)
        }
    case _ =>
        List()
}
```

However this cannot be compiled as tail recursive due to line 4 in the code. So to get around this I can redefine the function as follows:

```
def recurse2(strs: List[String], accum: List[Int] = List()): List[Int] = strs match {
    case h :: t =>
        try {
            recurse2(t, h.toInt :: accum)
        }
        catch {
            case _ : java.lang.NumberFormatException =>
                recurse2(t, accum)
        }
    case _ =>
        accum.reverse
}
```

So my question is this. Is there an idiom I can use in scala that will allow me to do this tail recursively but without having to pass a variable to accumulate the values?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: You want to turn all numeral strings into numbers and discard the rest? Use `.collect` with a partial function patternmatching numeral strings.

Comment: Expanding on devoured elysium:

remember that a tail recursive function is basically equivalent to a while loop where the accumulator(s) are variable(s).  Can you think of a way to do this with a while loop where you're not using a variable?  If you can, then you can translate that while loop into a tail recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `recurse` method is just for illustration but for completeness I'll add to @pamu's answer how to use standard functions:

```
  def foo(ss: List[String]): List[Int] = 
    ss.map(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
      .filter(_.isDefined)
      .map(_.get)
```

or

```
  def foo(ss: List[String]): List[Int] =
    ss.map(s => Try(s.toInt))
      .collect { case Success(n) => n }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I see programmers write a helper function which takes many arguments (internally) which is specific to method/algorithm you are using. They write a minimal interface function around the ugly internal function which is tail recursive and takes only inputs required and hides the internal mechanism.

```
def reverse(input: List[Sting]): List[Int] = {
 def helper(strs: List[String], accum: List[Int] = List()): List[Int] = 
  strs match {
      case h :: t =>
          try {
             helper(t, h.toInt :: accum)
          }
          catch {
              case _ : java.lang.NumberFormatException =>
                 helper(t, accum)
          }
      case _ =>
          accum.reverse
  }
  helper(input, List.empty[Sting])
}
```